# Websphere parallel install ear

Tags: parallel-processing, websphere, ear

I have a Webspehere 7.0 and deploy there EAR file. But deploy is very slowly
How is it possible to parallelize the deploy of the EAR file to the Websphere 7.0?

Comment: How do you deploy your apps? Using wsadmin scripting or IBM Admin Console?

Comment: @adimoise91 using wsadmin scripting

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options that you can consider to speed up deployment:

- you should verify that there are no unneeded or redundant jars contained in the application like javaee, jta, jstl, database drivers etc.. This is especially often, when application is build with Maven.
- you can also shrink ear by putting some large rarely changing libraries into shared libraries defined in WebSphere
- you may change some deployment settings

  - switch to RMI instead of SOAP
  - manually copy end expand EAR
  - increase heap size of dmgr and node agents.

For more deep discussion on this topic check this page [Options for accelerating application deployment](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0812_webcon/0812_webcon.html)

Comment: @Arjan - dont upper case names jta, jstl, jee in this case, as these are not technology names but jar names, and they are always lowercase.

Comment: Okay, you're right, sorry. But I still question whether there's a jar named "jee". It's almost universally called "javaee", see e.g. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api

Comment: @Arjan Ok, I agree maybe it was to big simplification.